# SSL secure WCF message security service hosted on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a c# written WCF service published on IIS that uses Message Security with certificates.
I am asked to also cover it by SSL, but as far as I know, it's not supported by WCF (combination of SSL - transport security with nonSSL - Message security).
Is it possible to use UrlRewrite to enable this or is there any other way?

Comment: As far as I know, Url Rewrite can't do it, [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) does not include SSL secure.

Comment: Is there any other way to keep using message security with certificate but with secure transport (SSL)?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out, that probably the only possibility is to use external reverse proxy to be able to additionally secure the communication by SSL. In reality it would not make the data much safer and it would slow down the processing.
If someone has other idea/knowledge, please let me know and I will reconsider this answer.